# Windows 7 - No audio unless start using it immediately after startup

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have a Lenovo thinkpad with Windows 7. There is no audio unless immediately after startup I open an application (ex. youtube, media player) and start using it. I guess something takes over sound process but I cannot find it when I am looking over open processes in task manager.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Have you checked the volume mixer?

Comment: The volume mixer seems normal.

Comment: When the sound is unavailable, you should be able to see any audio-using program in the volume mixer.